# Drupal Custom Content Type Node Reference Field to Custom Panels Page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-panels

I'm a little bit of a Drupal newbie here so still getting my bearings while doing site architecture and really utilizing modules to their fullest. Basically what I have setup here is a custom content type of "College" that has several custom fields for image logos and what not.

I have also utilized the Panels Module which I am using to create all of my custom pages because I like the Graphical drag and drop interface for content editing for my end users. Within many of the custom Panels Pages I have an area that is designated for listing out the "College" content type fields, and I have implemented this by using a view of the "Colleges" that can be used as a block and added to the Panels Pages wherever I like. This is all well and good. The way I have this set up is that each College Content type has it's own corresponding custom Panels Page.

What I want to make happen is that when you are on a specific College's corresponding Panel's Page, I do not show that College in the View. The College Content Type and Panel's Page need to be related somehow, but I am not sure how to do this the best way. I have tried using a node reference field and choosing to reference a "Panel", but my custom Panels Pages are not coming up in the dropdown after adding the node reference field to the college content type.

What else can I do here? What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!!!